# Embedded components cutting a complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a irreducible subvariety $X $ of $\mathbb{A}^n$, which is a complete intersection, if we cut out $X $ with a subspace of $\mathbb {A}^n $, can the obtained scheme have embedded components?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by subspace? A linear subspace, i.e. a subvariety cut out by linear equations?

Comment: Yeah, a linear subspace.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X \subset \mathbb A^4$ be cut out by $x^2-z,xy-w$. This is a complete intersection, since the two polynomials form a regular sequence. Furthermore we have $k[x,y,z,w]/(x^2-z,xy-w) \cong k[x,y]$, i.e. $X$ is irreducible.

Cut out $z=w=0$ and we get $Y \subset \mathbb A^2$ cut out by $x^2,xy$, the common example for a scheme with an embedded component.

Comment: Well done, Moos!